Can you convert int*[N] to std::span<const int * const>?
I have the following code:
#include <span>

int* pointers[3];
std::span<const int* const> s = pointers;

GCC accepts this, but Clang (compiling libstdc++) rejects it, stating:
<source>:4:29: error: no viable conversion from 'int *[3]' to 'std::span<const int *const>'
    4 | std::span<const int* const> s = pointers;
      |                             ^   ~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:230:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int *[3]' to 'const span<const int *const> &' for 1st argument
  230 |       span(const span&) noexcept = default;
      |       ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:192:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const int *' against 'int *'
  192 |         span(type_identity_t<element_type> (&__arr)[_ArrayExtent]) noexcept
      |         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:199:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>' against 'int *[3]'
  199 |         span(array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>& __arr) noexcept
      |         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:206:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>' against 'int *[3]'
  206 |         span(const array<_Tp, _ArrayExtent>& __arr) noexcept
      |         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:218:2: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with _Range = int *(&)[3]]
  218 |         span(_Range&& __range)
      |         ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:213:8: note: because '!is_array_v<remove_cvref_t<int *(&)[3]> >' evaluated to false
  213 |           && (!is_array_v<remove_cvref_t<_Range>>)
      |               ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/span:238:2: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'span<_OType, _OExtent>' against 'int *[3]'
  238 |         span(const span<_OType, _OExtent>& __s) noexcept
      |         ^

See Compiler Explorer
I was under the impression that std::span can be constructed from ranges if only a qualification conversion (such as int* to const int * const) is required, so which compiler is correct here?
This is quite likely just a Clang/GCC interoperability quirk, considering that the code also compiles with -stdlib=libc++.

Reject by msvc too Demo

It appears only a top level qualification conversion is supported.  std::span<int* const> s = pointers;

Isn't that related?

This works: std::span<int const* const> s(pointers, pointers+3);

@alagner no, it's not. It would violate const-correctness if this was std::span<const int*>, but we are making std::span<const int* const>, which is perfectly fine from a const-correctness viewpoint. Note that binding a reference such as const int* const (&r)[3] = pointers; is accepted by all compilers, and std::span is spiritually the same as r here.

The fact that clang still doesn't work with -libstdc++ suggests that this is a divergence in the language rather than the library.

This is a reduced example.

@康桓瑋 Even more reduced. Clang accepts the direct binding to a reference, just not the type deduction.

Barry's reduced example shows the relevant difference between Clang and GCC:
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t N>
void f(const int* const (&)[N]);

int main() {
  int* pointers[3];
  f(pointers);  // accepted by GCC, rejected by Clang
}

This deduction is governed by [temp.deduct.call]. According to p3

[...] If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

Here, P is the parameter type, const int* const (&)[N], so it is replaced by const int* const [N].
Then, p4 instructs as follows:

In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow a difference:

If the original P is a reference type, the deduced A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be more cv-qualified than the transformed A.
The transformed A can be another pointer or pointer-to-member type that can be converted to the deduced A via a function pointer conversion and/or qualification conversion.
[...]


The "deduced A" means P after template arguments have been substituted. So in other words the compiler will try to deduce N that makes const int* const [N] identical to the argument type, int* [3]. Obviously that is not possible, so we need to check if one of the bullets allows the deduction to succeed.
The original P is a reference type, so the deduced A could be more cv-qualified than A, that is, the deduced A could be int* const [3]. But arguably const int* const [3] is not allowed by this bullet because that type is not just more cv-qualified than int* [3]; it has "deep const" added to it as well.
The second bullet also doesn't apply here because the "transformed A" is the original A, the type int* [3]. According to p2, A is transformed if the original P is not a reference type. Such a transformation would have made A into int**. But since the original P was a reference type, the transformations don't occur. That means the second bullet here doesn't apply because the transformed A is not a pointer type, it's still the original type int* [3]. The second bullet would apply to a case such as
template <class T>
void g(const T*);

int main() { int* p = nullptr; g(p); }

In Barry's example, Clang is right according to the letter of the law but I think GCC is right according to the spirit. It seems that this case falls into a gap in the wording but there is no reason why I would expect it to be rejected, given that this reference binding (if the deduction were to succeed) would be analogous to a qualification conversion (see [over.ics.ref]/1.3). I think this should be reported as a CWG issue.

Richard thinks that this is a Clang bug.

You can always create a non-const span first and assign it to the const span. If you use constructor template argument deduction (CTAD), the syntax is only slightly more verbose than what you have right now:
std::span<const int* const> s = std::span{pointers};

As for why the original code works with GCC/libstdc++ and clang/libc++ but not with clang/libstdc++:

In libstdc++ the constructor #9 from other spans is implemented in a standard-conforming manner with explicit, i.e. no implicit conversions are allowed. This means that for your case to be matched with libstdc++, you need the constructor #4 (template< std::size_t N > constexpr span( std::type_identity_t<element_type> (&arr)[N] ) noexcept) to match. GCC allows that, but clang generates the message candidate template ignored: could not match 'const int *' against 'int *' (which is wrong in my opinion, see below).

In libc++ the constructor #9 is not declared as explicit (which is technically not what the standard says), so the compiler will allow an implicit conversion first to the span type with int as the type, and then the conversion to the final span type with the const int as the type.


In my opinion this is a bug in clang (because the std::type_identity_t template exists explicitly for the purpose of considering conversions, and int* is definitely convertible to const int *), and the reason it doesn't pop up with libc++ is that libc++ doesn't declare one of span's constructors as explicit, allowing the code to compile, but using a different constructor than what you would expect from the standard. (And if clang ever fixes that bug the lack of explicit in that constructor will probably make the overload resolution ambiguous in this case, causing the current span implementation of libc++ to not compile with a fixed clang. Probably, not completely sure about that one.)

std::span<const X> has no constructor taking a X[N] C array reference (as of c++26).
So you have to construct the span manually in that case:
span<const int* const> s{ pointers, 3 };

Yes, it is a bit painful, and using a std::array instead of the C array does not help a lot, for the same reasons (but a std::array
will always be better than a c array).
As well, it would be nice to have a span::operator< span<const T> >...

It has no such constructor mandated by the standard, nor implemented in the libc++ (as of 19.1) but the libstdc++ seems to be a bit more permissive (in 14.2).

And it seems that your error is with (clang,libstdc++) and not (clang,libc++) so it might also be a small incompatibility between the latest clang and the latest libstdc++.
